# Adicionar dependência no android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Eu queria saber onde exatamente coloco uma dependência como essa no android studio:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.code-troopers.betterpickers</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse formato que indicou é o formato usado pelo [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) para declarar uma dependência.

O [Android Studio usa o Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Introduction) para gerir dependências e construir as aplicações.

Há duas formas de declarar uma dependência no Gradle:

Usando os identificadores `group`, `name` e `version`

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers', name: 'library', version: '2.2.1'
}
```

Usando a forma curta `group:name:version`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.2.1'
}
```

O Android Studio usa o repositorio ***jCenter*** para resolver as dependências, isso é declarado no *build.gradle* de forma automática quando é criado um projecto novo.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O Android Studio usa o **[Gradle](https://kamaondev.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/porque-voce-deve-trocar-o-maven-pelo-gradle/)** como builder e gerenciador de dependências, mas ainda utiliza o repositório central do Maven para resolver estas dependências.

Quando preciso de algo do tipo:
**1** - eu pesquiso pela dependência no google com o prefixo "maven"
**2** - no site do repositório do maven, clico na aba gradle que ja da a linha que devo adicionar no script de build do gradle.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para adicionar a dependência no Android Studio, abra o arquivo build.gradle do projeto, e adicione a dependência no grupo ***dependency*** como no exemplo de um script completo:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.11'
    compile 'de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'

    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.0.3'

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 8
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

*O link para o texto do gradle é uma sugestão pessoal, pois achei bastante interessante e direta a abordagem.*